# How to schedule events and create triggers with mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql-event

I have 3 tables in my database, tbl_events, tbl_exceptions, tbl_archived_events

**tbl_events** stores a list of events, this contains the following fields

```
**eventID** => int(4)Key, AutoIncrement
eventREF => VARCHAR (4) ( will remain the same for each version of the event and will be used to check for an exception)  
eventName => VARCHAR (30) (Name of the event)
eventType => int(4) will determine the type of event it is
eventLocation => VARCHAR (30) hold the event location data
eventDate => DATETIME hold the date of the event
eventStart => DATETIME hold the start time of the event
eventEnd => DATETIME hold the end time of the event
isReoccuring => int(2) Default to 1 which means it is reoccurring 
frequency => VARCHAR (10) will be either Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Yearly
eventLink => VARCHAR (30) will contain a link to the event page if there is one
eventValid => int(2) Will be set to 1 if the event is on and 0 if there is an exception
```

**tbl_exceptions** stores a set of events and the dates they are not held. There might be certain times when a reoccurring event might not be held. This table will hold the following field information

```
**exceptionID** KeyField, AutoIncrement => int(4)
eventREF => VARCHAR (4) Holds the event ref number
exceptionDate => DATETIME , Hold the date of the exception
```

**tbl_archive_events** will store the past events that have expired. this table will store the same data as the tbl_events table but for past events only

```
**eventID** => int(4)Key, AutoIncrement
eventREF => VARCHAR (4) ( will remain the same for each version of the event and will be used to check for an exception)  
eventName => VARCHAR (30) (Name of the event)
eventType => int(4) will determine the type of event it is
eventLocation => VARCHAR (30) hold the event location data
eventDate => DATETIME hold the date of the event
eventStart => DATETIME hold the start time of the event
eventEnd => DATETIME hold the end time of the event
isReoccuring => int(2) Default to 1 which means it is reoccurring 
frequency => VARCHAR (10) will be either Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Yearly
eventLink => VARCHAR (30) will contain a link to the event page if there is one
eventValid => int(2) Will be set to 1 if the event is on and 0 if there is an exception[/CODE]
```

So once an event has expired i would like mysql to do the following:

- 1/ if the event is a reoccurring event create a new event and set the
  eventDate date relative to the length of time specified in the
  frequently field relative to the existing event.
- 2/ if the new event
  eventREF is found in the eventException table then set the eventValid
  to 0
- 3/ once the event has expired copy the event to eventsArchive
  table
- 4/ delete expired event from tbl_events table

i have this so far

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE 
EVENT `new_event` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-07-24 03:00:00' 
DO BEGIN

       -- create new event
       SELECT eventID, eventREF, eventTitle, eventLocation, eventDate, eventStart, eventEnd, isReoccuring, frequency, eventType, eventLink, eventValid
       FROM tbl_events
       WHERE eventDate < now()

       --- for each event found create a new event
       INSERT INTO tbl_events (eventID, eventREF, eventTitle, eventLocation, eventDate, eventStart, eventEnd, isReoccuring, frequency, eventType, eventLink, eventValid) 


       -- copy expired events to tbl_archived_events
       INSERT INTO tbh_archived_events (eventID, eventREF, eventTitle, eventLocation, eventDate, eventStart, eventEnd, isReoccuring, frequency, eventType, eventLink, eventValid) 
       SELECT eventID, eventREF, eventTitle, eventLocation, eventDate, eventStart, eventEnd, isReoccuring, frequency, eventType, eventLink, eventValid
       FROM tbl_events
       WHERE eventDate < now();

       -- delete expired events from tbl_events
       DELETE FROM tbl_events WHERE eventDate < now();

END */$$[/PHP]
```

obviously the above is not correct and I'm not really sure what i am doing, would appreciate some help please
Thanks

Luke

Answer (score 2):

You can use mysql scheduler to run it each 5 seconds or every 1 one day.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Nobody uses this thing

---

CREATE EVENT yourevent 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 (SECOND,DAY) 
    DO
      CALL YOURSTROREPROCEDURE();

---

Create your SP separetly

Comment: thank you for your input, i will check out the link and see if i can get something working.